# Clang erroneous unneeded-internal-declaration warning?

Tags: compiler-warnings, clang++

clang++ (17.0.1) gives a warning for this code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace {
    void fun ()
    {
        std::cout << "fun\n";
    }
} // namespace

template<class T>
void tfun (T)
{
    fun();
}

template<> void tfun (int);
```

The warning goes away if `fun` is not inside an anonymous namespace.

Is this a compiler bug?

See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/df9TTPssx)